# How to update a SwiftUI view state from outside (UIViewController for example)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct CatView : View {

    @State var eyesOpened: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
       Image(uiImage: eyesOpened ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "OpenedEyesCat") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ClosedEyesCat"))
    }
}
```

I'm trying to integrate it with in a regular UIViewController.

```swift
let hostingVC = UIHostingController<CatView>(rootView: cat)
addChild(hostingVC)
view.addSubview(hostingVC.view)
hostingVC.view.pinToBounds(of: view)
```

Now in the UIViewController if I try to set the eyesOpened property I get a

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Accessing State<Bool> outside View.body`

How are we supposed to make this work? Are SwiftUI views not supposed to work in this scenario?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your `OctoCatView` struct? That error is from trying to modify a `@State` outside of `var body: some View`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. :) The internal structure of the Cat shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**@State** is the wrong thing to use here. You'll need to use **@ObservedObject**.

**@State:** Used for when changes occur *locally* to your SwiftUI view - ie you change eyesOpened from a toggle or a button etc from within the SwiftUI view it self.

**@ObservedObject:** Binds your SwiftUI view to an *external* data source - ie an incoming notification or a change in your database, something *external* to your SwiftUI view.

I would highly recommend you watch the following [WWDC video - Data Flow Through SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/)

Comment: Yeah, that one is on my whatch list... but haven't had the opportunity to see it. Thanks.

Comment: I just watch this WWDC Apple talk, Sorry to say it is one of the most vapid talks I ever watched.

Comment: The Video talks about ObjectBinding which has been deprecated :(

Answer (score -10):

There is something called the notification center that you could use.  In short, it is a way that views can communicate between each other without actually modifying anything in each other.

How it works is view A sends a notification to a central hub from which view B hears said notification.  When view B hears the notification it activates, and calls a function defined by the user.

For a more detailed explanation, you can refer to:
https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/

Comment: That really is far from the point. Not to mention a bad  design when you have direct access between the actors involved (controller and a view). It’s like telling your mom who is in the same room something through national television.