# SwiftUI: Fatal Error: Accessing State<String> outside View.body"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I hope you guys can help me out here, I'm fairly new to Swift in general.

I have a MainView, which is my rootViewController, in SwiftUI.

In there is a @State var myString : String that is bound to a Textfield.

Theres a button that presents a UIViewController "MyViewController" from the rootViewController when pressed.

The MyViewController has a delegate that calls a function delegateEnds in which I want to set the myString from the presentingViewController (line 11 of MyViewController.swift) to a certain value that a delegate (MyDelegate) delivers.

This is where the error is happening:

Thread 1: Fatal Error: Accessing State outside View.body

How can I resolve this problem? My goal is to present the UiViewController and get a string result from it down to the MainView's myString variable that is bound to the Textfield, so that the TextField updates right away.

Since I can't change the @state variabe from outside the view appearently, is there any other way?

Thanks in advance!

MainView.swift:

```
struct MainView : View {  

@State var myString: String = ""

     var body: some View{  

          VStack{  

               TextField($myString)  

               Button(action:{  

                    let rootVC : UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!  

                    rootVC.present(MyViewController.init(), animated: true, completion: nil)  

                    })  

               }  

}  

}
```

MyViewController.swift:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController , MyDelegate {  

     override func viewDidLoad(){  

super.viewDidLOad()  

//...some delegatestuff

     }  

     func delegateEnds(withResult result: String!){  

if let presenter = presentingViewController {  

              let pres= presenter as! UIHostingViewController  

              pres.rootView.myString = result.resultString  

          }      

          self.dismiss(animated: true, coimpletion: nil)   

     }  

}
```

Comment: Appearently not all of them. This has the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718802/how-to-update-a-swiftui-view-state-from-outside-uiviewcontroller-for-example

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
[How to update a SwiftUI view state from outside (UIViewController for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718802/how-to-update-a-swiftui-view-state-from-outside-uiviewcontroller-for-example)
@State is wrong if your data source is external.
Use @ObjectBinding instead.

Comment: What is `@ObjectBinding`? Neither SwiftUI nor Combine has such a property wrapper.