# Updating custom SwiftUI button UI via their toggle state variable?

Tags: swiftui

This is so easy to do in UIKit, struggling with SwiftUI. I have in my ContentView a series of custom buttons. Each has their own @State variable which governs whether are toggled on or off - and update accordingly.

```
struct AudioToggleButton: View, Hashable {

    // Some Details omitted here for brevity
    @State private var toggled = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            toggled.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: iconString)
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .foregroundColor(self.toggled == true ? .white : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                .background(self.toggled == true ? .black : .white)
                .font(.title)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle()
                    .stroke(self.toggled == true ? Color(UIColor.darkGray) : Color(UIColor.lightGray), lineWidth: 6))
            .padding(4)
    }
}
```

I have in my ContentView where they are placed (a bunch). I have a regular vanilla button in my ContentView where I want to turn off all the buttons (the toggle) at once. I can change each by having them in an array & looping over them - and having a func in the custom button's struct that sets the @state variable - but the UI never updates to change because of the var change.

How can I turn off (toggle) any buttons that are toggled on from outside the buttons?

Comment: Btw. You don’t need to test a Bool in Swift, use like `self.toggled ? .black : .white`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array will cause issues with updates, as you have discovered.

I expect you might get some answers on how to solve it with that approach. But an alternative way to do it is to have a simple struct that holds all the flags. This way, you only need one state variable. To reset all the flags at once, just create a new instance of the struct.

Like this:

```swift
struct MyFlags {
    var flag1 = false
    var flag2 = false
    var flag3 = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flags = MyFlags()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("Flag 1", isOn: $flags.flag1)
                Toggle("Flag 2", isOn: $flags.flag2)
                Toggle("Flag 3", isOn: $flags.flag3)
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                flags = MyFlags()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, the state variable with all the flags would be held by the parent class and you would pass each individual flag to an `AudioToggleButton` as a `Binding`. Something like:

Something like:

```swift
struct AudioToggleButton: View, Hashable {

    @Binding var toggled: Bool

    // everything else as before
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flags = MyFlags()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                AudioToggleButton(toggled: $flags.flag1)
                // etc.
            }
            Button("Reset") {
                flags = MyFlags()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I used this approach and I like it. Did not think about creating a new instance of the struct to "reset" things.

Answer (score 0):

To control this state from outside the button, you need to make this state accessible from the parent view. This can be achieved by using `@Binding` and `@State` together.

```
struct AudioToggleButton: View, Hashable {
   // Some Details omitted here for brevity
   @Binding var toggled: Bool

   var body: some View {
       Button(action: {
           toggled.toggle()
       }) {
           Image(systemName: iconString)
               .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
               .foregroundColor(self.toggled == true ? .white : Color(UIColor.lightGray))
               .background(self.toggled == true ? .black : .white)
               .font(.title)
               .clipShape(Circle())
               .overlay(Circle()
                  .stroke(self.toggled == true ? Color(UIColor.darkGray) : Color(UIColor.lightGray), lineWidth: 6))
           .padding(4)
       }
   }
}
```

Now, you can control the `toggled` state from the parent view. Here's an example of how to use the `AudioToggleButton` in a parent view and control its state, so you can do like this:

```
struct ParentView: View {
   @State private var buttonToggled = false

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           AudioToggleButton(toggled: $buttonToggled)
           Button("Toggle Button") {
               buttonToggled.toggle()
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to change the states from a class, not a View struct using this approach and I get "Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update."

Comment: It's because you're trying to access a ```@State``` property from outside the view. I should be used only within a view and it's not designed to be accessed from [other classes or structs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718802/how-to-update-a-swiftui-view-state-from-outside-uiviewcontroller-for-example)